# Divisor Function Proofs

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

I am trying to decipher the proofs to the following statements:
Let $d$ be the divisor function, then;

- show that $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a square
- Show that for a given $n\geq 2$, there are infinitely many positive integers $x$ such
  that $d(x) = n$.

I am trying to go through them, but I keep getting stuck along the way. Help answering the question would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the first : If $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k}$, then $d(n)=(a_1+1)...(a_k+1)$

Note that all factors have to be odd, if $d(n)$ is odd.

Hint for the second : Use $N=p^{n-1}$ , $p$ any prime.